# Trouble with mysql SUM of multiple datetimes

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp, sum

In my database, the times are stored as "datetimes" (I don't know if this is the issue or not- I tried both datetime and timestamp). The structure looks like:

```
ID | START_DATE          | END_DATE
1  | 2011-10-10 08:15:00 | 2011-10-10 12:00:00
2  | 2011-10-11 09:00:00 | 2011-10-11 14:30:00
3  | 2011-10-12 08:45:00 | 2011-10-12 10:15:00
```

I am trying to get sum of total seconds between all the start and end times. Here's what I have:

```
$times = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(TIMEDIFF(end_date, start_date))
AS timesum FROM schedules");

$timetotal = mysql_fetch_assoc($times);

echo $timetotal['timesum'];
```

Now, the sum should be 38700, but when I run the above query, it returns 100500. What's wrong with the query?

Comment: `100500` is the total from adding all the schedule records together: http://www.sqlize.com/91Ypqt7Ylf.  Also, the values for each schedule are `34500`, `53000`, and `13000`, respectively.  Where are you getting the `38700` from? http://www.sqlize.com/5IlL9a9cOa

Comment: I just echoed it onto the screen and the value is correct. sch_id is another field in the table, I was just trying to keep it simple for this post.

Comment: Oh I had it in seconds. ManseUK's answer below solved the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot sum datetime values - you need to convert to seconds first ....

```
SELECT SUm(time_to_sec(TIMEDIFF(end_date, start_date)))
AS timesum FROM schedules
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert your `TIMEDIFF` to seconds using the `TIME_TO_SEC` function to correctly get the sum in terms of seconds:

```
$times = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end_date, start_date)))
         AS timesum FROM schedules")
```

Without explicitly converting to seconds with `TIME_TO_SEC` the `SUM` function treats a `TIMEDIFF` as a floating point number. Give it a try on your first row to see what I mean:

```
$times = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(TIMEDIFF(end_date, start_date))
         AS timesum FROM schedules WHERE ID='1'")
```

should yield:

```
$times = 34500.000000
```